# How to save view from canvas to PNG file?

Tags: android, png, android-canvas

I created canvas that can be used to draw some shapes on it.
How can I save its content to PNG file on user's SD card?

Answer (score 7):

check out this link [this link](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/10/save-image-in-sdcard.html)
In this link you can find the method

```
void saveImage() {

  try {
      String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

      File f = new File(filename ,"myImage.png");
      f.createNewFile();
      System.out.println("file created " + f.toString());
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f);
      Bitmap bitmap = showImage(urlStr);
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }      
 }
```

which is used to save the image that you got into a bitmap.  and check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882164/creating-bitmap-from-canvas-java)  for getting bitmap from canvas

hope this helps you.

Happy coding

Comment: after compressing bitmap you probably don't need it anymore and can bitmap.recycle()

Answer (score 2):

Canvas is just a means to draw to the Bitmap.

You should have created Canvas with `new Canvas(myBitmap);`. So when you draw on the Canvas, it draws to your bitmap.

so using `myBitmap` Do the following (code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573676/saving-as-a-png-image-in-android):

```
String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/test.png";
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
/* Write bitmap to file using JPEG or PNG and 80% quality hint for JPEG. */
myBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, stream);
stream.close();
```