# How to do Image Steganography on android?

Tags: android, image-processing, steganography

Hi i'm creating a project and for part of it I want to encode a message (that the user types in), into an image that the user has on his/her phone. 
However I'm new to this and I've struggled to find resources on steganography for android. 
So my question is what are the basic principles/methods or what do I need to do to encode a string into an image?
Thanks!

Almost working, but its encoding right, when I try convert a character to a value if its a symbol or 0, it gets converted to -1.

code:-

Encoding:-

```
 public void encodeImg(ImageView imgEncrypt){
     String test = "hello";

     Bitmap bmap;
     BitmapDrawable bmapD = (BitmapDrawable)imgEncrypt.getDrawable();
     bmap = bmapD.getBitmap();


     Bitmap operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmap.getWidth(),bmap.getHeight(),bmap.getConfig());

     for(int i=0; i<bmap.getWidth(); i++){
         for(int j=0; j<bmap.getHeight();j++){

             int p = bmap.getPixel(i, j);

             int r = Color.red(p);
             int g = Color.green(p);
             int b = Color.blue(p);
             int alpha = Color.alpha(p);

             if( i < 1 && j < 5 ){
                 int value = Character.getNumericValue(test.charAt(j));
                 alpha = value;
                 Log.w("myApp", "code has executed");

                 operation.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(alpha, r, g, b));
             }





         }
     } 
     imgEncrypt.setImageBitmap(operation);
     Save savefile = new Save();
     savefile.SaveImage(this, operation);

 }
```

Decoding:-

```
     public void decodeImg(ImageView imgEncrypt){
     String message = "";
     TextView hiddenMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hiddenMsg);

     Bitmap bmap;
     BitmapDrawable bmapD = (BitmapDrawable)imgEncrypt.getDrawable();
     bmap = bmapD.getBitmap();


     Bitmap operation = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmap.getWidth(),bmap.getHeight(),bmap.getConfig());

     for(int i=0; i<bmap.getWidth(); i++){
         for(int j=0; j<bmap.getHeight();j++){

             int p = bmap.getPixel(i, j);

             int r = Color.red(p);
             int g = Color.green(p);
             int b = Color.blue(p);
             int alpha = Color.alpha(p);

             if( i < 1 && j < 5 ){

                 int value = alpha;
                 char c = (char) value;
                 message += c;

                 Log.w("myApp", "code has executed");


             }





         }
     }

     hiddenMessage.setText(message);


 }
}
```

Comment: Just alter the transparency (alpha) component of each pixel of a png file. Be sure it's a **png, not a jpg** - or the compression will ruin your hidden text.

Comment: Draw the entered text onto a canvas and save it? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533471/how-to-save-view-from-canvas-to-png-file

Comment: @DerGolem I saw an app where you would select and image and encode it with a string, then you would send it to whoever, and they can decode the string  from the image using that app. I was trying to replicate that.

Comment: @DerGolem is that what you thing they did with that app?

Comment: @user3482398 Yes, exactly. But you can do the same thing with an audio file or even a text. Steganography is the art of hiding something into something else, without making it notice to a casual interceptor.

Comment: @DerGolem how would I retrieve the text that I've written?

Comment: By using the opposite operation. If you used the Alpha channel of the pixels of a png file to hide your characters, re-read the Alpha value of the color and convert it to aa character.

Comment: @DerGolem You see the alpha pixel, can I only change that to a different number value or characters as well? Sorry, I'm just sort of confused on how to change the alpha value of pixels into a message

Comment: Say your original pixel had this color: #88512063. 88 is the Alpha. You want to change this to represent the character **A** (code = 65 dec, 41 hex). Then set your new pixel color to #41512063. When you will read that pixel again, you will get 41 as its alpha color. In decimal, it is 65, which represents **A**.

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks for that I've almost got everything working, but I'm having an issue again! I've turned the characters to integers using this code, ----> 'int value = Character.getNumericValue(test.charAt(j));' <------'j' being the int on my for loop, and then I've set that to alpha, however when I try turn it back I get 5 letter 'y's with two dots on top, so I was wondering how do I get about this? ---------->If it helps I tried this with a normal picture and I am getting the same result 5 'y's instead of the word hello

Comment: Do you save the modified image and then load it for decoding? If yes, what format do you save it in? Some formats don't save the alpha channel and it defaults to 255. The y with diairesis has ascii value of 255. It is also possible that you haven't probably set your image to argb format (but set only to rgb) and the alpha value defaults to 255 whenever you fetch it. If you change the alpha value of a pixel and then fetch it straight after, what value do you get back?

Comment: Yea, I've just changed it top save it as a .png file, now when I try decode no letters show, just a blank line @Reti43 + The image I load is a .png, andI save it as a png now too.

Comment: I've tried doing red pixel, and that's not producing results either ://

Comment: The ASCII table allows you to use the standard printable characters 32 to 127. Charactres in the range 128-255 will give unpredictable results (prdictable, but varying between the different encodings). See this: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: Oh, so is my conversion wrong? and would you happen know the method I'd need to do it right?

Comment: That probably explains, when I was just looking at my debugger, why Char c stayed as an empty variable, even though the numbers were being converted right

Comment: During decode value contains the integers that got translated to say hello in each loop (which were '17,14,21,21,24'), but when I try convert it back using 'char c = (char) value;' c isn't set to anything, so nothing gets added to the String message

Comment: Thanks so much I added 87 to alpha when I was encoding and it all works!

Comment: I've run into something again, when I type in a symbol or 0 I get the value of the character to be -1 any idea how I'd get around that?  @DerGolem

Comment: `when I type in a symbol or 0 I get the value of the character to be -1` Well, if the symbol (or "strange" characters, like **ö**), you'll probably go off the (0-255) range of a byte values.

Comment: @user3482398, can you share the correct solution as an answer here? Thanks

Comment: @FrankN.Stein, hi mr Frank. I'm facing the same problem as thread starter. I got bunch of "y" character with a dot on top and wondering if you can place the correct code snippet as an answer to this question?

Comment: These are "unprintable ASCII" chars (I guess you're using Windows), as presented in a standard text file editor (namely, Notepad). If you'd use a decent text editor (i.e.: Notepad++), capable of displaying hex bytes, you'd see something different.